# Adding border style to the tag description

Tags: feature-request, tags, design

Previously the description and the links related to the tags were with in the box, I mean it was applied with border-style CSS property. After the left nav implemented in MSE and SO, the border style was missed.

Can we apply the border-style for the tag's description section again.

> [image: Adding border style for tag description]